# Netbeans not opening New Project Dialog

Tags: netbeans-8

After installation, Netbeans open fine, Open Exiting Project, Or Existing File works. However Netbeans doesn't show New Project or New File Dialog, whether selecting it from menu or from the toolbar. Netbeans version is 8.2, Ubuntu version is 16.04. It is a fresh install, and Oracle jdk-9 installed.

update-alternatives point to oracle-java.

Uninstalled and Reinstalled Netbeans, without any success.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with JDK 9, switched back to JDK 8

Change netbeans.conf file and adjust JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans 8.2 seems to have some problem with JDK11 as well. Do not know whether it has been fixed, since even after dowloading JDK11 the problem persists.

Without deleting the newer ones you can set the path to the previous versions i.e. JDK8 and it works.

Open the following file

**/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf**

Look for `#netbeans_jdkhome=`

set the path to the older version of java:
  netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home"

and restart the netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing but i changed the jvm in update-alternative to open-jdk jvm and it starts working.

Comment: how?           you did that

Answer (score 0):

I closed netbeans 8.2, commented out the reference to the JDK home in the netbeans.conf file, in the root of the netbeans 8.2 folder

```
# netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"
```

When I restarted the navigation pane that were previously missing appeared as they should.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. In Program Files, go to Java
2. For me, my computer has already downloaded the latest JDK. Check to see if there are JDKs in your folder
3. Delete the duplicate/latest JDK's

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem started after a Mac OS upgrade to 10.15.4.
None of the solutions worked.
I uninstalled NetBeans and reinstalled it, and it worked.